# how to install 3rd party ros packages?

Tags: ros, 3rd-party-package

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi there, I'm a beginner of ROS. Normally a ros package from official website includes explanations and instructions on installation and usage. However, when I download a 3rd party package from github (like this one:  https://github.com/RobotnikAutomation/agvs_sim.git), I clone it in \catkin_ws\src\ and catkin_make and always got cmake error telling me that .cmake file was missing. Can anyone tell me how to install it for use? Many thanks!

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/265018/how-to-install-3rd-party-ros-packages?/) by [turbocruiser](https://answers.ros.org/users/30945/turbocruiser/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1 on 2017-06-28

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2018-08-13**:
Why did you delete the question? It's a perfectly good question, but just happens to probably have been answered by/in #q252478.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Please see if #q252478 helps.

---

Originally posted by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) with karma: 86574 on 2017-06-28

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0